# MDX query returns unexpected (null)

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, ssas-2008

I`ve faced strange problem with MS SSAS 2008 R2 (10.50.4000.0): two MDX queries which I expect to return the same result behave differently:

This query returns **correct** numbers:

```
select
    [Measures].[Fact Count] on 0
from
    [Cube]
where
    [Dimension].[Attribute].&[id]
```

While this one, which is expected to be equivalent to the first query returns **(null)** from time-to-time (see details below).

```
select
    [Measures].[Fact Count] on 0
from
(
    select
        [Dimension].[Attribute].&[id] on 0,
    from
        [Cube]
)
```

Some details

1. Problem is not persistent. It appears and disappears **randomly** (!) on different databases from different physical servers.
2. We are using incremental data import and non-lazy processing. There is no strict correlation between problem appearance and data imports. But we continue investigation in this direction.
3. Adition of other members to axis of the subselect fixes the problem i.e.  *{[Dimension].[Attribute].&[id1], [Dimension].[Attribute].&[id2] on 0}* works fine.
4. Several dimensions are affected. All of them have integer key. Prolbem appears both on visible and hidden dimension attributes.
5. Addition of extra dimension to the second axis of the *subselect* fixes the problem for some pairs of dimensions, i.e. filter *[Dimension1].[Attribute].[&id] on 0* fails, but filter *[Dimension1].[Attribute].[&id] on 0,[Dimension2].[Attribute].[&id] on 1* works.
6. We have two measure groups with several measures each. All dimensions are related to some (default) measure in first measure group but some dimensions are only related to the second measure group. Problem appers only on the dimensions of the second type.

Does anyone have idea about the reasons of such strange non-determenistic behavior of MS OLAP?

Thanks.

Comment: MDX gets my vote for the worst language I've ever worked with. This is further confirmation of my opinion. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe this discussion will help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/3f0a2aba-93de-4f67-8402-181798a6225f

Comment: @MikeHoney once you get some sort of understanding for mdx it is very pretty; certainly compared to spaghetti sql. In terms of power it seems to out gun DAX.

Comment: @whytheq - Oh I understand it well enough thanks, I've successfully written thousands of lines of MDX, some of it quite complex. It's that experience that has formed my opinion.  So, do you have the solution for the OP?

Comment: @MikeHoney I cannot replicate this problem, and haven't experienced "strange non-determenistic behavior". In terms of the difference between sub-select and where clause I thin Michele's link is sufficient.

Comment: @MikeHoney can you instruct me how to replicate this nondeterministic behaviour that the user is experiencing with their instance of SSAS?